# Real-time database synchronization across Amazon Oracle RDS instances

Tags: amazon-rds

Currently we have an Amazon EC2 instance and Oracle RDS in Europe. For performance reasons we also want to set up a server in Asia, but we need to be able to keep the contents of the database in sync across two sites. Apparently Amazon RDS doesnt support RAC, so I was wondering if there are other solutions to keep the two databases in sync in real-time?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if Data Pipeline could used to do the synchronization or not.